# Determinant of $M = \begin{pmatrix} I_n&iI_n \\iI_n&I_n \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

Calculate the determinant of the following matrix:

$M \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $$M = \begin{pmatrix} I_n&iI_n \\iI_n&I_n \end{pmatrix}$$

I find that that $\det M = 2^n$ is that correct and if not please provide some details.

Comment: are the $I_n$ block matrices?

Comment: write how you found $2^n$

Comment: Yes... I think you're right

Answer (score 4):

There exists a generalization of Cofactor expansion called Laplace expansion. It is a very cumbersome method but it has a very natural and useful special case. Let 
$$\begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ B & C\end{pmatrix}$$
be a matrix composed of block-matrices $A,B,C,0$ of appropriate dimensions so that this matrix makes sense. The matrix $0$ is a is a zero matrix. Then this result says
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ B & C\end{pmatrix} = \det (A) \det (C)$$
i.e that the method for expanding upper triangular matrizcs actually also extends to 'upper-triangular-block-matrices'.

For your matrix we can add $-i$ times the second 'block-row' to the first block-row to get
$$\det M = \det \begin{pmatrix}2 I_n & 0 \\ iI_n & I_n \end{pmatrix} = \det(2I_n) \det(I_n) = 2^n$$

Comment: This generalizes nicely to $$\det\begin{bmatrix}A&xA\\
xA&A\end{bmatrix}=(1-x^2)^n\det(A)^2$$ (+1)